# Exponential of a matrix sum

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Im trying to prove the following identity of the exponential of a matrix:
$$ e^{A+B}= e^{A}e^{B} $$
where $A,B \in \mathbb{M}^{n\times n} $ s.t their product commute. Here is my procedure until now:
\begin{eqnarray}
 e^{A+B} &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (A+B)^{n} \\
 &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} A^{k}B^{(n-k)}\right] \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{A^{k}}{k!}\frac{B^{(n-k)}}{(n-k)!}
\end{eqnarray}
the previous equation can be rewritten as:
$$ e^{A+B} = \sum_{0\leq k \leq n\leq\infty}  \frac{A^{k}}{k!}\frac{B^{(n-k)}}{(n-k)!} $$
but I am stuck, in how to change the indices of the sum in order to obtain the last equality:
$$ e^{A+B}= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{m}}{m!}\frac{B^{j}}{j!} = e^{A}e^{B} $$

Any help or advice is well received.

Comment: This is the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)

Comment: The 2nd to last equation is covering the $(k,n-k)$  plane's upper right quadrant one diagonal at a time for each value of $n$  (never repeating a term).  The last equation just covers the quadrant in a different order.

Comment: it takes more work but this is an easy consequence of the Lie Product Formula, which you'll find to be useful elsewhere when dealing with matrix exponentials